# Issue while calling function in databricks

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have created a currency conversion function in databricks when I call function it is giving error:

I have tried following code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType

df_curr1 = spark.read.table("table")

def currency(from_currency,to_currency,date,rate_type):
    
    df_select = df_curr1.select(df_curr1["col0"].alias("BaseCurrency"), df_curr1["col1"].alias("TargetCurrency"),df_curr1["col2"].alias("EffectiveDate"),df_curr1["col3"].alias("ExpressInBaseCurrency"),df_curr1["col4"].alias("Ratetype"),df_curr1["col5"].alias("Rate"))

    #display(df_select)

    df_select = df_select.withColumn(
        "Rate",
        
        when(
            (df_select["ExpressInBaseCurrency"] == 2),

            1/df_select["Rate"]
        ).otherwise(df_select["Rate"]) )
    display(df_select)
    
    if from_currency == to_currency :
        rate = 1.0

    elif df_select.where(col("BaseCurrency") == from_currency).count() > 0:
        if df_select.where((df_select.BaseCurrency == from_currency ) & (df_select.TargetCurrency == to_currency ) & (df_select.EffectiveDate <= date) & (df_select.Ratetype == rate_type)).count() > 0:
            
            selected_df = df_select.filter( (df_select.BaseCurrency == from_currency ) & (df_select.TargetCurrency == to_currency ) & (df_select.EffectiveDate <= date) & (df_select.Ratetype == rate_type) )
            selected_df = selected_df.orderBy(selected_df["EffectiveDate"].desc())
            selected_df = selected_df.limit(1)
            rate = selected_df.select("Rate").head()[0]
        else:
            selected_df = df_select.filter( (df_select.BaseCurrency == from_currency ) & (df_select.TargetCurrency == to_currency ) & (df_select.EffectiveDate <= date) )
            selected_df = selected_df.orderBy(selected_df["EffectiveDate"].desc())
            selected_df = selected_df.limit(1)
            rate = selected_df.select("Rate").head()[0]
    elif  df_select.where(col("BaseCurrency") == to_currency ).count() > 0:
        
        if df_select.where((df_select.BaseCurrency == to_currency ) & (df_select.TargetCurrency == from_currency ) & (df_select.EffectiveDate <= date) & (df_select.Ratetype == rate_type)).count() > 0:
            selected_df = df_select.filter( (df_select.BaseCurrency == to_currency ) & (df_select.TargetCurrency == from_currency) & (df_select.EffectiveDate <= date) & (df_select.Ratetype == rate_type) )

            selected_df = selected_df.limit(1)
            display(selected_df)
            rate = selected_df.select("Rate").head()[0]
            rate = 1/rate

        else:
            if df_select.where((df_select.BaseCurrency == to_currency ) & (df_select.TargetCurrency == from_currency) & (df_select.EffectiveDate <= date)).count()>0:
                selected_df = df_select.filter( (df_select.BaseCurrency == to_currency ) & (df_select.TargetCurrency == from_currency) & (df_select.EffectiveDate <= date) )
                selected_df = selected_df.limit(1)
                display(selected_df)
                rate = selected_df.select("Rate").head()[0]
                rate = 1/rate
            else:
                selected_df = df_select.filter( (df_select.BaseCurrency == to_currency ) & (df_select.TargetCurrency == from_currency)  )
                selected_df = selected_df.limit(1)
                display(selected_df)
                rate = selected_df.select("Rate").head()[0]
                rate = 1/rate


    else:
        if df_select.where((df_select.TargetCurrency == from_currency ) & (df_select.EffectiveDate <= date) & (df_select.Ratetype == rate_type)).count() > 0:
            selected_df = df_select.filter((df_select.TargetCurrency == from_currency ) & (df_select.EffectiveDate <= date) & (df_select.Ratetype == rate_type))
            selected_df = selected_df.orderBy(selected_df["EffectiveDate"].desc())
            selected_df = selected_df.limit(1)
            first_value = selected_df.select("Rate").head()[0]
        else:
            selected_df = df_select.filter((df_select.TargetCurrency == from_currency ) & (df_select.EffectiveDate <= date))
            selected_df = selected_df.orderBy(selected_df["EffectiveDate"].desc())
            selected_df = selected_df.limit(1)
            first_value = selected_df.select("Rate").head()[0]
        
        if df_select.where((df_select.TargetCurrency == to_currency) & (df_select.EffectiveDate <= date) & (df_select.Ratetype == rate_type)).count() > 0:
            selected_df2 = df_select.filter((df_select.TargetCurrency == to_currency) & (df_select.EffectiveDate <= date) & (df_select.Ratetype == rate_type))
            selected_df2 = selected_df2.orderBy(selected_df2["EffectiveDate"].desc())
            selected_df2 = selected_df2.limit(1)
            second_value = selected_df2.select("Rate").head()[0]
        else:
            selected_df2 = df_select.filter((df_select.TargetCurrency == to_currency) & (df_select.EffectiveDate <= date) )
            selected_df2 = selected_df2.orderBy(selected_df2["EffectiveDate"].desc())
            selected_df2 = selected_df2.limit(1)
            second_value = selected_df2.select("Rate").head()[0]

        rate = second_value / first_value


    return rate

currency_udf = udf(currency, FloatType())
invoice_currency_col = df_fact2["TransactionCurrency"]
currency1_col = df_fact2["Currency1"]
document_date_col = df_fact2["DateofFirstContact"]
rate_type_col = df_fact2["OpportunityType"]

# Apply the currency function using withColumn
df_fact2 = df_fact2.withColumn("rate1", currency_udf(invoice_currency_col, currency1_col, document_date_col, rate_type_col))
```

im getting following error when i executed above code

> PicklingError: Could not serialize object: RuntimeError: It appears
> that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast
> variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on
> the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information,
> see SPARK-5063.

here is input data

```
df_fact2
TransactionCurrency | Currency1 | DateofFirstContact | OpportunityType
AED | SAR | 2023-05-24T19:59:59.000+0000 | PUR
```

here is expected output

```
df_fact2
TransactionCurrency | Currency1 | DateofFirstContact | OpportunityType | rate1
AED | SAR | 2023-05-24T19:59:59.000+0000 | PUR | 1.02124
```

here is df_curr1 samples

```
col0 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 
AED | AUD | 2022-12-31T18:30:00.000+0000 | 2 | PUR | 2.51325
AED | SAR | 2021-01-31T19:59:55.000+0000 | 1 | PUR | 1.02124
```

please help me where i am going wrong

Comment: You are trying to use spark inside this function. Try creating that dataframe outside and pass it. and provide some sample input data and expected results.

Comment: i tried spark outside still its giving same error and also i've updated sample input and expected output

Comment: can you provide `df_curr1 ` samples

Comment: yes, i've updated

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can not use spark context or reference it when you are using UDFs.
To use like that broadcast the variables and use them.
Here, i am converting the `df_curr1` to pandas and broadcasting it.

Try below code block.

```
df_select = df_curr1.select(
    df_curr1["col0"].alias("BaseCurrency"),
    df_curr1["col1"].alias("TargetCurrency"),
    df_curr1["col2"].alias("EffectiveDate"),
   df_curr1["col3"].alias("ExpressInBaseCurrency"),
   df_curr1["col4"].alias("Ratetype"),
   df_curr1["col5"].alias("Rate"))
   
df_select = df_select.withColumn("Rate",when((df_select["ExpressInBaseCurrency"] == 2),1/df_select["Rate"]).otherwise(df_select["Rate"]))
```

Next, broadcasting it.

```
fact_ent_df_data = sc.broadcast(df_select.toPandas())
```

Alter, your function as below. With respect to pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

def currency_df(from_currency, to_currency, date, rate_type):
    df_select = fact_ent_df_data.value
    
    if from_currency == to_currency:
        rate = 1.0
    elif df_select[(df_select["BaseCurrency"] == from_currency) & (df_select["TargetCurrency"] == to_currency) & (df_select["EffectiveDate"] <= date) & (df_select["Ratetype"] == rate_type)].shape[0] > 0:
        selected_df = df_select[(df_select["BaseCurrency"] == from_currency) & (df_select["TargetCurrency"] == to_currency) & (df_select["EffectiveDate"] <= date) & (df_select["Ratetype"] == rate_type)]
        selected_df = selected_df.sort_values("EffectiveDate", ascending=False)
        rate = selected_df["Rate"].iloc[0]
    elif df_select[(df_select["BaseCurrency"] == to_currency) & (df_select["TargetCurrency"] == from_currency) & (df_select["EffectiveDate"] <= date) & (df_select["Ratetype"] == rate_type)].shape[0] > 0:
        selected_df = df_select[(df_select["BaseCurrency"] == to_currency) & (df_select["TargetCurrency"] == from_currency) &(df_select["EffectiveDate"] <= date) & (df_select["Ratetype"] == rate_type)]
        selected_df = selected_df.sort_values("EffectiveDate", ascending=False)
        rate = 1 / selected_df["Rate"].iloc[0]
    else:
        from_df = df_select[(df_select["TargetCurrency"] == from_currency) & (df_select["EffectiveDate"] <= date) & (df_select["Ratetype"] == rate_type)]
        to_df = df_select[(df_select["TargetCurrency"] == to_currency) & (df_select["EffectiveDate"] <= date) & (df_select["Ratetype"] == rate_type)]
        if  not from_df.empty and  not to_df.empty:
            first_value = from_df.sort_values("EffectiveDate", ascending=False)["Rate"].iloc[0]
            second_value = to_df.sort_values("EffectiveDate", ascending=False)["Rate"].iloc[0]
            rate = second_value / first_value
        else:
            rate = None
    return  float(rate)
```

Next, create udf and call the fucntion.

```
currency_pd_udf = udf(currency_df, FloatType())
df_fact2 = df_fact2.withColumn("rate1",currency_pd_udf(invoice_currency_col, currency1_col, document_date_col, rate_type_col))
display(df_fact2)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much... code is executing as expected

Comment: this code works only with less data

Comment: when the dataframe has 478702 it is giving  following error PythonException: 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rate' referenced before assignment',

Comment: The error is not related to dataframe. It is saying you are trying to access variable rate before it is initialized.